# Section to Skew-Symmetrization Map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix skew-symmetric matrix.  Define the map
$\mathbb{R}^{d^2}\to Skew_d$ by
$$
B\mapsto B^{\top} - B.
$$
Does this map have a continuous right inverse?

Comment: Just look at $2\times2$ matrix examples and see what happens, there it is clear that the matrix $B$ is not unique. What do you think of other $n$?

Comment: Let me rephrase/clarify.  Does there exist a continuous right-inverse to this map (which is clearly surjective).

Comment: In your new statement of the question, the role of $A$ is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following addresses the question as first stated, which read,  if I recall correctly:

"Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix skew-symmetric matrix.  Does there necessarily exist a unique $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that

$A = B^T - B."   \tag 0$

To which I responded:

Pick any symmetric matrix

$C = C^T; \tag 1$

let

$B = -\dfrac{1}{2}(A + C);  \tag 2$

then

$B^T =  -\dfrac{1}{2}( A^T + C^T) = -\dfrac{1}{2}(-A + C), \tag 3$

since

$A^T = -A, \tag{3.5}$

and

$B^T - B = -\dfrac{1}{2}(-A + C) - (-\dfrac{1}{2}(A + C)) = A.  \tag 4$

These calculations indicate the existence of an infinite number of matrices $B$ such that (4) holds; thus no such $B$ is unique.

The preceding result may be used to address the present question of the existence of a continuous right inverse to the skew-symmetrization map, which we denote by

$\Sigma(B) = B^T - B. \tag 5$

According to what has been presented in the above, every skew-symmetric matrix is of the form $\Sigma(B)$ for some $B$.  Thus a right inverse $\theta$ to $\Sigma$ will assign to every skew-symmetric $A$ a matrix $\theta(A)$ such that

$\Sigma ( \theta(A)) = A. \tag 6$

Picking any symmetric matrix $C$ as in (1), we set

$\theta(A) = -\dfrac{1}{2}(A + C) \tag 7$

as in (2); it is easy to see that such a $\theta$ is continuous, since both matrix addition and division by $2$ are continuous operations.  Now (6) is simply the result of our preceding calculations, and $\theta$ is a right inverse of $\Sigma$.

Comment: But isn't this obvious just by dimensions of the considered spaces; whereas the existence of a continuous selection is not as clear to me..

Comment: @AIM_BLB Given any surjective linear map $V\to W$ there is a linear section $W\to V$. Just pick any subspace $W'$ of $V$ complementary to the kernel; the restriction $W'\to W$ is an isomorphism whose inverse $W\to W'$ composed with the inclusion $W'\to V$ gives a linear section $W\to V$. For finite-dimensional topological vector spaces, linear maps are continuous.

Comment: Indeed, if we call your skew-symmetrizer $\phi(B)=B^T-B$, its restriction to the skew matrices is just $\phi(B)=-2B$, so the linear map $\psi(B)=-\frac{1}{2}B$ is the section, aka right inverse. It is typical to normalize the skew symmetrizer as $\phi(B)=(B-B^T)/2$ though so it is a projection onto the subspace of skew matrices (in which case skew matrices' inclusion is the section).